# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' - php7.+++

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, servidor

Ao concluir a instalação de PHP7.++ obtive o seguinte erro após realizar todas as etapas do Tutorial de Configuração de Driver SQL Server PDO para php, restart apache2:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1710-and-1804

Answer (score 1):

Após algumas verificações e load's dos PDO's do php7 (Apache) identifiquei que 10-pdo.ini precisa ser carregado antes da library do PDO pdo_sqlsrv.so então removi do php.ini a seguinte linha:

**extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so**

Adicionei o seguinte arquivo para o load na pasta conf.d: 
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/**30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini**
com a extenção:
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so

Isso é valido também para Cli e FPM (arquivos php.ini)
Após as configurações é necessário reload em apache2. Somente relembrando que antes você precisa seguir todos os passos de instalação e configuração de todos os pacotes e suas dependências, seguindo o tutorial disponibilizado pela Microsoft para php7+ e SQL Server (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-debian-8-and-9) precisa estar tudo certo antes...
Funcionou comigo perfeitamente.

Agora funciona em ubuntu 18.04 lts e Debian8. thanks =)